# Drupal changing links

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi

I'm using Drupal's Forms API in my module, and I'm attempting to output a link as part of some markup:

```
//$output = l('Result', 'document/1234');
$output = '<a href="document/1234">Result</a>';

$form['results'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $output,
)
```

I've tried use both a simple string and the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) function and in both cases when the page is rendered, the link does not work, and when I inspect the element, it is mangled like this:

```
<a href=" 1234"="" document="">
```

and the closing tag is missing.

So far as I can see I'm not doing any post-processing of any kind on the markup before it is rendered.

In other places in my module I have created links like this and they are output normally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very strange, it sounds like another module must be changing it...do you have translation/string replacement modules installed by any chance?

This should help you get it around it in the mean time, you can use render arrays and [`theme_link`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_link/7) to output a link like this:

```
$form['results'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'link',
  '#text' => 'Result',
  '#href' => 'document/1234',
  '#options' => array(
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('cool-class'), 'id' => 'cool-id'),
      //REQUIRED:
      'html' => FALSE,
  ),
);
```

Note that `html` in `attributes` is a required key.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried experimenting with this, but all I can get is the same result, with an additional error message in a red box above the element: *Notice: Undefined index: #href in drupal_pre_render_link() (line 5332 of /var/www/mysitename/includes/common.inc).*

Comment: Sorry the `#path` key should be `#href`, I've updated the answer above. If you're having no problems using `l()` elsewhere then it must be a problem in your module or to do with the particular path you're using...does it work if you try a completely different path than `document/1234`?

Comment: Clearly I'd got something screwy in my module somewhere.  I tried playing around with the various options for l() and I was still getting nowhere, so in the end I backed out all the changes I had done and redid it from scratch, and it all worked this time.  Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Pleasure, really glad you got it sorted :-)